# UWP- How would I go about referencing a variable string within a datatemplate?

Tags: c#, resources, uwp, datatemplate

To give a bit of context: In our application, we have a series of terms stored in a database. We internally reference our terms using some key, whereas our clients decide what text should show up in place of that. This has worked well for our web applications.

However for our UWP application, we have run into trouble in our DataTemplates. The way I understand it, data templates work like this:

```
<DataTemplate x:DataType="ObjectWithAllInformation">
    <Element Property={x:Bind PropertyOnAboveObject} />
</DataTemplate>
```

The problem is that we're wanting to bind something that exists outside of the context of this specific object. We want to do something like this:

```
<DataTemplate x:DataType="ObjectWithAllInformation">
    <Textblock Text="{Some sort of binding to a global terms object?}" />
    <Element Property={x:Bind PropertyOnAboveObject} />
</DataTemplate>
```

Is there a way to instantiate such a global resource that we can reference within the data template this way? Something that just popped in my head that I haven't tried yet, is that a custom user control might work, but it seems overkill for accessing a string. Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Comment: Does UWP not have `{x:Static}`? Can you not just declare this "global resource" in e.g. your App.xaml? Assuming not, it seems like you should still be able to use e.g. a converter or, perhaps better, a proxy view model object that exposes the "global" data via a instance property that can be bound to. Unfortunately, it's not even really that clear the nature of this other data you want to bind to. The question is hard to understand without a good [mcve] that shows clearly what you're trying to do and a more precise description of what the code does now and what you want it to do instead.

Comment: I don't think it has x:Static, but there is a StaticResourceExtension element that I don't completely understand at this point. As far as an example of what I want: I have a key value. I want to be able to use this key value to get the appropriate string from the database at runtime (it can't be known at develop time, only the key is known). I want to be able to access this string within the context of a DataTemplate. Using a converter with my key passed in as a converter parameter is what I'll be attempting tomorrow, though I'll have to work around the async data access part =)

Comment: Looks like the converter worked! I still have all kinds of questions about efficiency (since the converter is going to be running this search to get the string for each item in my list, instead of being able to pass a string into the template and reuse it), but this works for now.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the localization mechanism as presented in [this quick-start](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh965326.aspx)

In summary, you would create a resources file (.resw) in a known folders inside your solution "Strings/*culture-code*" - where *culture-code* is the language of your resources. You define the strings there and then reference them via the x:Uid property on your textblock

```
<DataTemplate x:DataType="ObjectWithAllInformation">
    <Textblock x:Uid="resource1" />
    <Element Property={x:Bind PropertyOnAboveObject} />
</DataTemplate>
```

and the corresponding resource file would have

```
resource1.Text: "whatever static text you need to define"
```

Notice that when you define the resource you are using the same value you used in the x:Uid field, and prefix it with the property that you need to set with that value, in your case "Text". You can use this mechanism to set values to other properties if needed, like Headers, PlaceholderText, etc...

Comment: The thought did cross my mind, but it wouldn't work. The vast majority of our clients are in an English locale, and these terms are client-defined after deployment time, not pre-defined at develop time. Basically the text is implemented dynamically, and we need a way to reference this dynamic text within the context of a DataTemplate.